# session scope in struts-config.xml

Tags: struts1

I want to know how to use Session in the Struts...
There is a tag in the "action" element which says "scope=". Is there anything to do with this in the session management.
Plese explain me with the following example. Suppose my first screen is accepting the username and the password. I want to use the username entered at this screen on the ,say 2th screen.So how to do this.
If I am suppose to use the normal approch like "session.setAttreibute(key,value) and session.getAttribute(key) then what is the use of the "scope= " field in the action element.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It defines where the page's action form is, request or session. It's not related to info that the user needs to carry around the entire site.

Comment: Oh, didn't notice the question was pretty old.